# Binding to a Service that lives in a Xamarin Bound Java Library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an imported Java Library, which is a "Bindings Library" project in my solution.

I'm trying to Bind to the service that lives in that 3rd party Library from another project in the solution.

3rd party Library documentation [in java] is pretty straight forward:

Declare the MeshService object in the Activity class:

```
private MeshService mService;
```

Bind to the service inside onCreate:

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, MeshService.class);
bindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

When I'm trying to bind using the following code:

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MeshService));
mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection(this);
BindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
```

There is an exception thrown on the first line

```
  Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class   "com.csr.mesh.MeshService" on path:DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/DeakoMesh.Android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/DeakoMesh.Android-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

When I'm trying to bind using another piece of code:

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent("com.csr.mesh.MeshService");
mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection(this);
BindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
```

there is no exception, but service binding never happens and mServiceConnection is a null. (please see code below)

Question:
How do I bind to a service in another project ?
What context should I provide instead of "this" ?

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MeshService));
```

Code for mServiceConnection:

```
class ServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
MainActivity activity;

        public ServiceConnection(MainActivity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            activity.meshService = ((MeshService.LocalBinder)service).Service;                
            activity.isBound = true;
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            activity.meshService = null;
            activity.isBound = false;
        }
    }
```

Huge thanks in advance for any tips on this!

also posted on xamarin forums here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44647/binding-to-a-service-that-lives-in-a-bound-java-library?new=1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Binding to your Library doesn't work properly, otherwise you should be able to see AutoCompletion suggestions and wouldn't get such errors. 
Checkout this [Article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/http://). Here is detailed explained how to Bind a Android Library